# WARNING is issued when using embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using embedded tomcat(v_**8.0.33**) to run my java application. It is throwing following error in console:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/servlet-name'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/servlet-class'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param/param-name'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param/param-value'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param/param-name'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param/param-value'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/init-param'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet/load-on-startup'.
g.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app/servlet-mapping'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'web-app'.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:04 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 11, 2016 2:53:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

I think its mapping to correct web.xml file but somehow not able to parse it tags, dont't able to figure out why. Is it due to version of this tomcat(something may be deprecated and I am using)?

below is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>ResourceLoader</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>sran.api.ifscLookup.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Api/*</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be anytime in future if someone also struck at this point, the workaround is to avoid using web.xml deployment descriptor because there is problem in XML parsing logic in webapp-runner.

Instead use **-->** In your *Main* class containing tomcat instance:

```
Tomcat.addServlet(context, "yourServletName", resourceConfig());
context.addServletMapping("/yourApi/*", "yourServletName");



 private ServletContainer resourceConfig() {
        return new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(
                new ResourceLoader().getClasses()));
    }
```

**ResourceLoader.java**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;



public class ResourceLoader extends Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // register root resource
        classes.add(classWhereYouDefinedUrlEndpoint.class);
        return classes;
    }
```

This might save your time :)